# How to hide foreign architecture?

Tags: debian, aptitude, dpkg

I have an `amd64` Debian but I had to install some `i386` packages. I don't want to remove this foreign architecture, I just would like to hide it so that, for example, when I seach for *libc* in `aptitude` I don't see two entries:

```
...
v   glibc-2.19-1
v   glibc-2.19-1:i386
...
```

but only one entry for my proper architecture. Is there a way to do it? I found a lot on how to remove foreign architecture from `dpkg`, but I don't really want to do this, as I want to keep the `i386` packages. I just want the packages lists to be clearer.

I also tried adding `[amd64]` after words `deb``deb-src`in`/etc/apt/sources.list`and the`sudo aptitude update`, but this also didn't help.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know an configuration option to enable this by default, but while searching you can add `~rnative` to show only packages from your native architecture. E.g.

```
aptitude search glibc~rnative
```

Comment: This is not an ideal solution, but it's very useful. Many thanks!